# RSS feed keeps extending past the height of table

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone have a look and tell me where/how I may add the height of 375px for the RSS feed? I am using a RSS widget from RSS Dog to post a feed on my site, I do not have access to the style.css because it is hosted on the RSS Dog site. It provides a java script to insert into my html code. There is no height adjustment on the widget. No matter what do or how I try to add a height adjustment of 375px to the java script it keeps going past it and runs down the page. Everything else looks properly aligned. I have tried other widgets but this is the only one that offers a transparent background. 
**this is my code ...**

```
    <table width="625" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="375" align="left" style="background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; width: 625; height: 375;">                      
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" class="blog" ><p>

     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.rssdog.com/index.htm?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apocalypseos.com%2Fforum%2Findex.php%3F%2Frss%2Fforums%2F1-news-and-announcements%2F&amp;mode=javascript&amp;showonly=&amp;maxitems=0&amp;showdescs=1&amp;desctrim=0&amp;descmax=0&amp;tabwidth=95%25&amp;showdate=1&amp;utf8=1&amp;linktarget=_blank&amp;bordercol=%23rrggbb&amp;headbgcol=%23rrggbb&amp;headtxtcol=%23rrggbb&amp;titlebgcol=%23rrggbb&amp;titletxtcol=%23rrggbb&amp;itembgcol=%23rrggbb&amp;itemtxtcol=%23rrggbb&amp;ctl=0" >
        </script> 
          <noscript> 
            You apparently do not have JavaScript enabled on your browser lest you would be viewing an RSS Feed here from <a href="http://www.rssdog.com/">RSS Dog</a>
            </noscript></p></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**this is the script i was given from RSS Dog...**
        You apparently do not have JavaScript enabled on your browser lest you would be viewing an RSS Feed here from [RSS Dog](http://www.rssdog.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the look of the widget through the `.rssdog` CSS class as stated next to the [code generator](http://www.rssdog.com/):

> Advanced Style Configuration:
>
> You can configure the output styles using CSS class "rssdog" (PHP and
>   Javascript methods, does not work with Iframe).  For example, to make
>   the font larger, place the following code in your HTML  
>   area:

```
<style type="text/css">
.rssdog {
    font-size:20pt;
}
</style>
```

So in your CSS file or in a style tag you could simply write:

```
.rssdog {
    height: 375px;
}
```

Also you can limit the number of items you receive with the `max items` option. The default value `0` means they will send you all items.